# Usage of | in PowerShell regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to split some text using PowerShell, and I'm doing a little experimenting with regex, and I would like to know exactly what the "|" character does in a PowerShell regex. For example, I have the following line of code:

```
"[02]: ./media/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/acs-01.png" | select-string '\[\d+\]:' | foreach-object {($_ -split '\[|\]')}
```

Running this line of code gives me the following output:

```
-blank line-
02
: ./media/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/acs-01.png
```

If I run the code without the "|" in the -split statement as such:

```
"[02]: ./media/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/acs-01.png" | select-string '\[\d+\]:' | foreach-object {($_ -split '\[\]')}
```

I get the following output without the [] being stripped (essentially it's just displaying the select-string output:

```
[02]: ./media/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/acs-01.png
```

If I modify the code and run it like this:

```
"[02]: ./media/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/acs-01.png" | select-string '\[\d+\]:' | foreach-object {($_ -split '\[|')}
```

In the output, the `[` is stripped from the beginning but the output has a carriage return after each character (I did not include the full output for space purposes).

```
0
2
]
:

.
/
m
e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers already explain what the `|` is for but I would like to explain what is happening with each example that you have above.

1. `-split '\[|\]'`: You are trying to match either `[` or `]` which is why you get *3* results. The first being a blank line which is the whitespace represented by the beginning of the line before the first `[`
2. `-split '\[\]'`: Since you are omitting the `|` symbol in this example you are requesting to split on the character *sequence* `[]` which does not appear in your string. This is contrasted by the code `$_.split('\[\]')` which would split on every character. This is by design.
3. `-split '\[|'`: Here you are running into a caveat of not specifying the right hand operand for the `|` operator. To quote the help from [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pU6sO2/1) when this regex is specified:

> (null, matches any position)
>
> Warning: An empty alternative effectively truncates the regex at this
>   point because it will always find a zero-width match

Which is why the last example split on *every* element. Also, I dont think any of this is PowerShell only. This behavior should be seen on other engines as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the pointer to the online regex tester.

Answer (score 2):

The Pipe character, "|", separates alternatives in regex.

You can see all the metacharacters defined here:
http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 0):

Walter Mitty is correct, `|` is for alternation.

You can also use `[Regex]::Escape("string")` in Powershell and it will return a string that has all the special characters escaped. So you can use that on any strings you want to match literally (or to determine if a specific character does or can have special meaning in a regex).